# PHP get image from another URL without having to add code to every page

Tags: php

I am updating a few websites and will not be renewing a domain that currently host all the images. The existing websites have hard coded links that I wish to update. Rather than hard coding them to a new url, I'd like to use a varibale/constant so if I need to make changes in the future, I can just make a single code change.

I did post a question before and changed it but got a warning about being blocked from the forum so sorry if I can't ask a question the right way.

I can get the images to display but only by putting the include/require on each page. My pages are set up with a header, body and footer so I'm trying to include/require the file in the header.php to make it available to all pages that require the images link.

Images are stored on mydomain1.

On mydomain2/general/declarations.php

```
define("HOST_IMAGES", "http://www.mydomain1");
```

In mydomain2/general/header.php I run the include:

```
include ('declarations.php');
```

If I echo HOST_IMAGES in the header.php this works

On mydomain2/index.php the header is included:

```
include ('http://www.mydomain2/general/header.php');
```

On mydomain2/index.php I now try to display images that are stored on mydomain1.

```
<td align="center">
    <?php
        echo '<img src="' . HOST_IMAGES . '/images/myimage.jpg" alt="Example of my image" width="200" height="150"'?>/></td>
```

The result is just a small image icon. When I inspect the image, the path shows as HOST_IMAGES/images/.... rather than mydomain1/images/...

So, am I right in thinking that the issue is setting a sitewide constant/variable so I don't have to run the include of every page I want to display images?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the constant defined whenever you use it, doesn't matter how you do it, clearly its not defined on your index.php at line you showed, if you had error reporting enabled you would see warning like:

`Warning: Use of undefined constant HOST_IMAGES - assumed 'HOST_IMAGES'`

Usually its done using mod_rewrite, where every non css, js, etc. file request is forwarded to index.php where you define your constant (or include it from file) and then based on the url you include desired php file.

There is also option if you have access to php.ini using this: [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), note that this will not work using `ini_set` because that is temporary.